# No success getting Intel AC 7260 wireless to work

Tags: 14.04, drivers, intel-wireless, firmware

I recently purchased an Asus 2-in-1 touchscreen laptop. NOTE: this machine does NOT have an Ethernet port! I am relatively new to Ubuntu, but it is essential that I get Ubuntu running on this machine (I have successfully installed Ubuntu on a desktop).

After much trial and error, I booted an .iso file on a UEFI USB stick and installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto a primary partition on my hard. Even before the permanent installation of Ubuntu, the wireless internet connection did not work. I hoped that permanent UEFI bootable installation would fix that. It did not, and I have Ubuntu permanently installed, alongside windows 8.1, but my wireless does not work whatsoever. Please note also that the wireless works while running in windows 8.1.

Here is some information about my system:

Asus Laptop (no ethernet port)

INTEL AC 7260 Wireless Card

From `uname -a`

```
Running Ubuntu 14.04. 64 bit. Kernel 3.13.0-32
```

I have read many posts extensively, and taken this problem as far as I can on my own. This is where I am so far:

`rfkill list` shows no hard or soft blocks for the wireless or bluetooth.

`lspci -v` shows Intel Wireless 7260 card

`lshw` shows *-network as UNCLAIMED and no driver is listed

After noting this, and doing some research, I downloaded the firmware package (via a usb drive onto my Ubuntu desktop) "iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.24.8.0" . I then copied the .ucode file in that package to /lib/firmware/ and I can see it listed there, along with other firmware packages

However, when I open the /etc/ modules file in vi I only saw `lp` and `rtc` listed. So I added `iwlwifi` to the file also (i don't know if this did anything or even that is ok). Therefore, I have the firmware package installed - i think! - but I do not believe I have the driver installed correctly (or if I even need it in addition to that firmware package in lib/firmware).

Again, I have been working on this issue for almost a week straight, and I have hit a stand still on my own. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does an `insmod iwlwifi` do?

Comment: As super user, 'insmod iwlwifi' gives the following message:  "insmod: ERROR: could not load module iwlwifi: No such file or directory"

Comment: As super user, 'modprobe iwlwifi" gives the following message:  "libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 7: ignoring bad line starting with iwlwifi"    So I took a look at that file, this is what it contains, after the comments:  "iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211"

Answer (score 0):

Also look through `/var/log/syslog` for errors during start up. Are there more USB ports? I use a USB -> ethernet dongle for situations like this until I solve the problem.

To expound, my usb -> eth adapter is an old Trendnet TU2-ETG. It's chipset is from ASIX who are linux-friendly and this networking device has always worked for me. In a [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1vmad6/any_usbethernet_adapter_you_know_it_works_good/), the user dfinf2 recommends the modern equivalent to my trendnet, a Unitek USB3.0 to Gigabit Network Adapter with ASIX AX88179 Chipset. This post also says the consensus is a Apple usb to ethernet device works.

Over my years, I have more than once had realtek devices not operate in linux and I'm surprised you are having problems with Intel hardware; their PCIe Gigabit adapters are the go-to for all of my linux server builds.

Comment: I have been researching usb-ethernet adapters for the last few hours, which do you use?

It looks to me like the Apple USB-Ethernet may be best. Do I need a driver for that, or is it plug and play in 14.04?

Comment: Here a few  oddities I noted in /var/log/syslog for my last boot

Comment: Mine is ancient but has the ASIX chip mentioned in dfinf2's answer here: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1vmad6/any_usbethernet_adapter_you_know_it_works_good/  He likes the unitek usb3 -> gigabit adapter: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00C2MLOJU/

Comment: After what each of you mentioned and reading reviews and the above articles, I ordered the adapter, and I should have it by this saturday. In the meantime, I will continue looking through the syslog. I may end up posting a portion of it as a comment, as I am not certain what I should be looking for.

Comment: K, I have seen articles where the AC 7260 wireless card had some intermittent connectivity and/or speed issues in linux, but I cannot find any cases that are identical to mine, where there is no connection whatsoever. From a GUI standpoint, I believe I have done all that I can do. Networking is enabled, and wireless is set to ipv4 and DCHP. It seems as if wlan0 just does not see wireless networks. I keep coming back to driver/firmware or compatibility issues, but again, I am relatively new to Linux and especially Ubuntu.